# How to add assign a calculated property value to an object?

Tags: c#, datetime, properties, nullable

I'm reading back a number of properties into the constructor of an object. One of the properties is a calculated off another property.

But when I create this object the calculated `Implementation_End_String` property value is always null:

```
    private string implementationEndString;
    public string Implementation_End_String {
        get{
            return implementationEndString;
        }
        set  {

            implementationEndString= DataTimeExtensions.NullableDateTimeToString(Implementation_End);
        }
    }
```

Question:

How can you pass in a calculated property to an object constructor?

This is a gist of the ctor and calculated property:

```
    private string implementationEndString;
    public string Implementation_End_String {
        get{
            return implementationEndString;
        }
        set  {

            implementationEndString= DataTimeExtensions.NullableDateTimeToString(Implementation_End);
        }
    }



    public DateTime? Implementation_End { get; set; }


    public ReleaseStatus(DateTime? implementationEnd)
    {

        //value is assigned at runtime
        Implementation_End = changeRequestPlannedImplementationEnd;



    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the field `implementationEndString`. Just make `Implementation_End_String` a read-only property and create the string from the other property when needed:

```
public string Implementation_End_String
{
    get
    {
        return DataTimeExtensions.NullableDateTimeToString(Implementation_End);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write it this way.

```
private string implementationEndString = DataTimeExtensions.NullableDateTimeToString(Implementation_End);

public string Implementation_End_String 
{
    get{ return implementationEndString; }
    set{ implementationEndString=value; }
    //if you don't want this property to be not changed, just remove the setter.
}
```

After that when you get the property value it will take the value of `DataTimeExtensions.NullableDateTimeToString(Implementation_End);`. In your code, when you try to get the implement returns `null`, because implementationEndString is `null`.

Comment: That gave a compiler error `A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property`. Clearly because NullableDateTimeToString is a static method. Not sure what to do in this case.